# Who first introduced the notion of attack graphs?

Tags: attacks

I've been searching the literature and haven't been able to pin it down. The concept probably existed long before the name was coined, but who is the invention/introduction of attack graphs attributed to?

EDIT: Here is an image of an attack graph. It essential models dependencies between vulnerabilities in a network, describing how an attacker may exploit and progress through a network.

Source: http://www.isaca.org/JOURNAL/ARCHIVES/2012/VOLUME-3/Pages/Haruspex-Simulation-driven-Risk-Analysis-for-Complex-Systems.aspx

[image]

Comment: Nice Graph ;) thnx for adding it.

Comment: I think it was Bruce Schnier

Comment: should be ... Bruce Schneier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comments mention, it was Bruce Schneier in a 1999 publication:

Bruce Schneier. Attack Trees: Modeling Security Threats. Dr. Dobb’s Journal, Dec 1999.